# Magento Bulk Import Functionality Best Approach

Tags: magento2, import, export, importexport

We are developing a multi vendor module . In this module vendor will upload an excel sheet to import simple and configurable products.

I have a few questions here to proceed. I need a better approach to import products.

The vendor, Excel sheet will contain labels such as "Fabric Care", "Fabric Type" etc. But to import data into Magento we need to know these attribute codes. I am able to get the attributesetid as well from the vendor file as we tagging attribute id and category id to the file name.

But while importing products how can I assign these CSV/EXCEL data values to Magento DB.

Today I have 3 categories, Lets say in future it will be 30 categories, but we can import products to each of these categories without any issue.

Suggestions please!!!

Comment: You need to write custom imported for that or use commercial extension with data mapping feature , our commercial extension support direct import from Excel and data mapping https://firebearstudio.com/the-improved-import.html